# How to save uploaded file in qq file uploader using php?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader uploader script on my website. I am searching for solution to save uploaded file in qq file uploader using php server side script.
I tried to request file using    `$_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name']`   but didn't works. Can anyone tell me php example to request and save file in qq file uploader?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the php example in the server folder of the file-upload github project.

Answer (score 0):

goto this url

http://code.google.com/p/php-axiom/source/browse/trunk/libraries/uploader/qqUploadedFileXhr.class.php?spec=svn41&r=41

or search about qqUploadedFileXhr

Answer (score 0):

Incase of those who may bump into this thread, here's a perfect example, helped me alot

http://wsnippets.com/fancy-profile-image-upload-crop-jquery-ajax-php/